# best way to automatically update reference page

Tags: php, xml, joomla, rss

Hi I am working on a website that has a list of references. Right now we are just copying the references that we find from the selected sources that our client has. What is the best way to go about building something that will automatically put these links on our website and keep it updated so we don't have to put it in by hand.

I was thinking of doing something with PHP and parsing but I'm not sure how that will work out without a server. I am also open to RSS and XML ideas if those are on the correct path.

PS This is a joomla site.

Comment: Are you adding these in to an article? If not, please mention where exactly they are being added as the answer may vary depending on this.

Comment: How can you run a Joomla site without a server?

Comment: @Lodder these are being added to an article.

Comment: @Nico. There are different types of severs we obviously have a web server. I only know of ways to automate this process using a different server running Windows Server and Task Manager.

Comment: @user3407419 You should edit your question to include more details. For example, how do you get the references? Where are the files stored, since they're apparently not stored on the same server as the website?

Comment: No we get them from another website. The website has given us access to them.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to write a crawler (provided you have permission to do so) to grab needed data.  We would need samples of the webpage you will be extracting information from as well as qualifiers you would use to be sure you are grabbing the correct references.